# Get the max latitude and longitude given radius (meters) and position

Tags: java, localization, geolocation, location

I need help with my code. 
I want to obtain the max latitude and the max longitude (in degrees) given a radius in meters and the actual position in latitude and longitude (in degrees). 
Can someone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post your code and tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: If the radius is quite small, you could just draw the tangents lines to your sphere around your point to get the longitude and the latitude from them, because you can consider the earth as flat on sufficiently small distances.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem, so we could fin a better solution? If you're trying to search over a DB objects in a range around points, consider seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387682/coordinates-comparison-in-database

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum" latitude and longitude? A single point that somehow embodies some concept of maximum, or two distinct points. In the first case you haven't provided enough information to tell us what "max" means. In the second, "max" is just r meters north and r meters west, and then you have to decide what you want if you cross the north pole or the 180-degree line.  In other words, "max" has no meaning without a lot more context.

Comment: I want to get all the points that are far from my position within a certain radius. My idea is to get all places around me within that radius (in DB I have all places with the relative coordinates).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, every degree of latitude contains `appx 111.1 km`, so it's easy to recalculate linear delta to latitude delta.

Second, linear appearance of 1 longitude degree is different and depends on latitude: small close to poles, large close to equator. Approximate equation is the following:

```
kmInLongitudeDegree = 111.320 * Math.cos( latitude / 180.0 * Math.PI)
```

Combining this, it's easy to get deltas of latitude and longitude that will cover your circle:

```
deltaLat = radiusInKm / 111.1;
deltaLong = radiusInKm / kmInLongitudeDegree;

minLat = lat - deltaLat;  
maxLat = lat + deltaLat;
minLong = long - deltaLong; 
maxLong = long + deltaLong;
```

For more precise calculation, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude (section *Length of a degree of longitude*).

On Android, to obtain how many meters one latitude degree contains, make 2 `Location` objects: one with current coordinates, and one with latitude shifted on 0.1 degree, then calculate distance between them and multiply by 10. The same with longitude.

Comment: @Gio you're welcome. I've just added last paragraph how to do it in more smart way on Android. It will give more precise result, since calculations are performed on WGS84 ellipsoid, not sphere.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm using it for Android!

Comment: Thank you very much! I "ported" it to Excel/Google Sheets :-) Cheers